# remote oracle connection from AIX to Linux Redhat

Tags: oracle-19c

I want to connect oracle database from AIX to Linux using user id and password only.  For that I have changed

```
tnsnames.ora

RATARA =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XX.XX.XX.XX)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = RATARA)
)

listener.ora

LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XX.XX.XX.XX)(PORT = 1521))
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
)
```

Above code, I have done in my AIX machine.  In the above change I have used IP address in place of HOST for both listener.ora and tnsnames.ora and PORT no has used for remote machine.

I have updated my .profile also in AIX machine:

```
export ORACLE_SID=RATARA
```

I have stop and started listener on AIX.  After that not able connect using @RATARA

RATARA oracle sid name is from remote(Linux) machine which I have set in my AIX.

I am able to connect using sqlplus <user_id>/@oracle_sid but I want to connect without using @oracle_sid since my entire code project uses without @oracle_sid.  Means I want to connect only sqlplus userid/pwd

Kindly provide me solution to connect using only user id and pwd for remote connection if it was missed anything for setting

Comment: now i am able to connect using export TWO_TASK=RATARA instead of export ORACLE_SID=RATARA.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution that would not require `@[remote_connection_info]` to connect to a remote database.

`ORACLE_SID` is only applicable on the actual database server, not a remote client, as this uses BEQ protocol to talk directly to Oracle processes and doesn't use the listener at all. Remote connections must use TCP protocol.

Also, `listener.ora` is only for the actual database server, not the remote client. Running a listener on the client won't do anything for you. – [pmdba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/203074/pmdba)